# FieldValue.serverTimestamp() sets a timestamp in inconsistent format

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My problem is that the format FieldValue.serverTimestamp() sets is inconsistent. On 'add' it's a string and on 'update' it's a DateTime.

With:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionName').add(
  {'lastEdited': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()},
)
```

It sets the date as (string):

[image: String serverTimestamp]

With:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collectionName').doc('id').update(
  {'lastEdited': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()},
)
```

It updates as a DateTime (this format would be preferable):

[image: DateTime serverTimestamp]

Because of this, some of the documents have a date that is string and some that is DateTime. This causes orderBy('lastEdited') to not work. Please do let me know if you have some insight to this behaviour. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with set() in place add()?and check this link (https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-convert-string-to-datetime)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I haven't, but I want the document snapshot to return from the operation. doc().set() returns void and I would have to do a write and a read from this one operation. Thanks though. I'll try it.

Comment: I just tried the code that uses `add()` and write the data as expected. Are you sure that the first code does that? Have you tried to use it in isolation?